# Expand and collapse Relativelayout by button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, expand

I have this RelativeLayout which expand and collapse on button click
it works fine on one button. 
I want to reuse same method on more two RelativeLayout 
in same layout
and expand using other two buttons.

This code is running fine. just want more layout to do same action.

Layout:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewmore"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="viewmore" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout

            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/expandable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="133dp"
                android:text="Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout


            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title 2"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewmore1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="viewmore" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:id="@+id/expandable1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title 3"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewmore2"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="viewmore" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:id="@+id/expandable2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Source Code:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout, relativeLayout1, relativeLayout2;
    Button viewmore, viewmore1, viewmore2;
    ValueAnimator mAnimator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewmore);


        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable1);
        relativeLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable2);


        viewmore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewmore);
        viewmore1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewmore1);
        viewmore2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewmore2);

        viewmore.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewmore1.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewmore2.setOnClickListener(this);


        relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        relativeLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                        mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                        return true;
                    }
                });


    }


    private void expand() {

        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private void collapse() {
        int finalHeight = relativeLayout.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

        mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            }
        });
        mAnimator.start();
    }


    private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);


        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                //Update Height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.viewmore:

                if (relativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    expand();
                } else {
                    collapse();
                }

                break;


            case R.id.viewmore1:


                break;

            case R.id.viewmore2:


                break;


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To continue with your approach, you will have to make the code apply to all three sections that you have laid out. To do this, you will need to change several of your methods to accept a `RelativeLayout` as an argument.

First, in your `onClick` listener, fill in the case blocks so each block calls `expand()` with the targeted `RelativeLayout` and maximum height. Call `collapse()` with the targeted `RelativeLayout`. You will then need to modify `expand()` and `collapse()` to handle the new arguments:

You will notice in the following code that I have changed how and where the animator is created. The animator will need to work with each `RelativeLayout`.

So, `onClick()` calls `expand()` which calls `slideAnimator()`. For each call, the `RelativeLayout` that is effected is passed as an argument. In this way, you can generalize the code to work with more than one `RelativeLayout`.

The pre-draw listener will also need to measure each expandable `RelativeLayout`.

Here is it all put together:

**MainActivity.xml**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout, relativeLayout1, relativeLayout2;
    Button viewmore, viewmore1, viewmore2;
    int height, height1, height2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewmore);

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable1);
        relativeLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable2);

        viewmore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewmore);
        viewmore1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewmore1);
        viewmore2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewmore2);

        viewmore.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewmore1.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewmore2.setOnClickListener(this);


        relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    relativeLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
                    height = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
                    relativeLayout1.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
                    height1 = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
                    relativeLayout2.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
                    height2 = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }


    private void expand(RelativeLayout layout, int layoutHeight) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValueAnimator animator = slideAnimator(layout, 0, layoutHeight);
        animator.start();
    }

    private void collapse(final RelativeLayout layout) {
        int finalHeight = layout.getHeight();
        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(layout, finalHeight, 0);

        mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            }
        });
        mAnimator.start();
    }


    private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(final RelativeLayout layout, int start, int end) {
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                //Update Height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = layout.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.viewmore:
                if (relativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    expand(relativeLayout, height);
                } else {
                    collapse(relativeLayout);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.viewmore1:
                if (relativeLayout1.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    expand(relativeLayout1, height1);
                } else {
                    collapse(relativeLayout1);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.viewmore2:
                if (relativeLayout2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    expand(relativeLayout2, height2);
                } else {
                    collapse(relativeLayout2);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey bro thanks it's working. but how to setVisibility(View.GONE) to keep it hide for first time.

Comment: @feltonjk My last comment (deleted) was just wrong. In the XML set android:visibility="gone"

Comment: but after i set set android:visibility="gone" it's not working and nothing visible. i had also tried relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) that too not working. can you tell me any other soluton?

Comment: @feltonjk Are you setting "gone" on the RelativeLayouts expandable, expandable1 and expandable2? If so, post your XML back here.

Comment: i have updated my xml in my questions. first code was working fine only when one relativelayout was there by using relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE). but now there are three layout. so how can i set this to all three layouts?

Comment: hey any solution?

Comment: @feltonjk I updated the answer earlier but I forgot to tag you. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create own custom expandable which extend android relative layout. On that custom view you can store expanded or collapsed status. As well as you can create custom attributes for define your view default status like expanded or collapsed. So you don't need to compare view status you will just call your toggle function which toggle your view expanded to collapse or vice versa

If you want to show collapsed view as a default view you should not change view visibility before onMeasure function and store your view measured height. If you change visibility on view constructor onMeasure function skip calculation for that view. You should toggle visibility on onPreDraw function.